# How to validate CDC data pipeline?

Tags: etl, pipeline, cdc

We have a MongoDB from which we consume CDC stream using custom python code. The CDC stream is dumped as files which is further consumed by spark which runs SQL on the files and dumps the result set into Kafka.

Questions:

1. how do you make sure there is no data loss in the pipeline
2. even if there is some loss, how to detect it and point it?

How are these handled? What is industry standard?

Answer (score 1):

This problem is particularly significant when the replication target happens to be Kafka, given the semantics of Kafka.  On the bright side, as long as you are not compacting topics it is possible to account for each message received by your consuming application.  The issue is having something in the Kafka message that gives you a monotonically dense increasing sequence number.   And there becomes issues if a consumer is only reading a subset of the data, as then not all of the sequence numbers would be read so it becomes hard to know if the data isn't there because its in a topic/partition you aren't reading or whether it is actually missing.

In the perfect situation your source has a sequence number in the user data.  From my many customer interactions, this is highly unlikely.   In my product (I work for IBM and own the CDC Kafka target engine), we allow a user to introduce a sequence number in the processing of the user data. You can consider doing this at both the subscription and topic/partition level. But at that point you are trusting that CDC captured the original data and did not have a "bug" in reading it in the first place.   Assuming you trust CDC to have at least read the source information from the source log.... you can then insert a sequence number with our product if you want to go the do it yourself route.

There are problems with this, in that the sequence number is for a given replication session.... so if there's an abnormal termination and you start the sub up, you might see replication with the new entries starting at zero.  You can solve this by storing the number you left off in the location you note the effective log position on the source that you've replicated to.

To solve all of this I designed something called the Transactionally Consistent Consumer....  It removes duplication and exactly resequences operations.  It has a checkpoint set of bytes that can be used to restart the source stream at any point previously seen (allowing for down stream data loss or incomplete processing).  It does require that you trust CDC originally captured all the changes (which is the point of an enterprise grade replication product).  If you happened to have source generated sequence numbers than that could work in conjunction with this.

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/idr/11.4.0?topic=kafka-transactionally-consistent-consumer

If your interested.

I did a presentation at the Kafka summit on the idea behind the technology ....

uh here....

https://www.confluent.io/kafka-summit-sf18/a-solution-for-leveraging-kafka-to-provide-end-to-end-acid-transactions/

Hopefully that helps a bit with how enterprise grade products approach this.

Cheers.

Comment: i liked the autoincrement logic

Comment: I didn't. Restore dbs.

Answer (score 0):

There is no industry standard, only hard work to capture potentially a few things, that never ends if the design is not simple from the outset.

It's like SOA eventing asynchronously --> hard to do, so not done often.

I work on such things and we test well and assume that may be some less will occur but we offset the cost vs. the benefit.

E.g. writing to AZURE Event Hub from a TIBCO Cloud Mashery API by a client and maipulating the Event Hub via a post insert AZURE Function, or CDC feed from ORACLE via Shareplex, KAFKA, Spark Batch KAFKA integration.